# Error services is forbidden on gitlab with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, pipeline, continuous-deployment

I cannot figure out how to establish interaction between gitlab and kubernetes.
I have a pipeline that creates a docker image that outputs in to console "hello world" on java.

I have a google cloud kubernets cluster. This cluster was created by gitlab.

Now I need to run my image on the cluster for this, I did the following job in the pipeline:

```
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    image: google/cloud-sdk
    services:
        - docker:dind
    environment:
        name: develop
    script:
        - kubectl version --short
        - kubectl config view
        - kubectl cluster-info
```

But i have an error after "kubectl cluster-info":

> To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl
> cluster-info dump'. Error from server (Forbidden): services is
> forbidden: User
> "system:serviceaccount:test-maven-cicd-12345678-develop:test-maven-cicd-12345678-develop-service-account"
> cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace
> "kube-system"

kubectl config view:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://ХХХ.ХХХ.ХХХ.ХХХ
  name: gitlab-deploy
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gitlab-deploy
    namespace: test-maven-cicd-12345678-develop
    user: gitlab-deploy
  name: gitlab-deploy
current-context: gitlab-deploy
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gitlab-deploy
  user:
    token: REDACTED
```

Comment: Regarding your error specifically you're missing permissions for your user and need to pass proper kubeconfig file to your pipeline to resolve, which is actually not recommended security-wise.

Instead, recommended way is to have something like ArgoCD on the cluster side that would pull changes instead of pushing changes from your CI. See my article here for a sample how to achieve this (note it uses GitHub Actions for CI instead of GitLab): https://itnext.io/building-kubernetes-cicd-pipeline-with-github-actions-argocd-and-reliza-hub-e7120b9be870